# Error:Expression has changed after it was checked - in constructor

Tags: angular, angular10

This is in my html file:

```
  <div id="my-div" [ngClass]="hasSetting ? 'my-container' : 'opacity-div my-container'">    
    <dx-load-panel
      #loadPanel
      [(visible)]="!hasSetting" >
    </dx-load-panel>
  </div>
```

And this is my component:

```
export class TurnoverWidgetComponent {

  departments: DropdownOption[] = [];
  hasSetting: boolean;

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) {

    forkJoin(
      this.myService.hasSetting(),
      this.myService.getDepartments()
    ).subscribe(
      ([hasSetting, departments]) => {
        this.hasSetting = hasSetting;

          this.departments = departments.map(item => {
            return {
              id: item.id,
              name: item.name
            }
          });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And I get the error Error:Expression has changed after it was checked - in constructor, from true to false and vice versa. From my research this error happens in events which happen after initialization of the component, however I have no such events, my change happens in the constructor. I tried putting it in the oninit event, the same thing happens.

Comment: Do you still have the error if you initialize like hasSetting: boolean = false; ?

Comment: Yes I do have it.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using ngAfterViewInit hook? the more proper one is ngOnInit in this situation. just replace the hook and you problem will be solved

Comment: @Andrei But I am not using ngAfterViewInit at all, where did you see I am using it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that we will be making a http call and changing the component variables when we get back an answer from it. In development mode, angular invokes the change detection twice to check if the values have not changed to ensure the code is not behaving unexpectedly. Here angular is complaining that the values have been changed after from the first time it has checked the component values.

Here is updated code to ensure angular detects changes after we change it in the http callback:

```
    export class TurnoverWidgetComponent implementes OnInit {
    
      departments: DropdownOption[] = [];
      hasSetting: boolean;
    
      constructor(
        private myService: MyService,
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
      ) {}

      ngOnInit() {

        forkJoin(
          this.myService.hasSetting(),
          this.myService.getDepartments()
        ).subscribe(
          ([hasSetting, departments]) => {
            this.hasSetting = hasSetting;
    
              this.departments = departments.map(item => {
                return {
                  id: item.id,
                  name: item.name
                }
              });
            this.cd.detectChanges(); // this will tell angular that we changed something and explicitly invoke change detection.
          }
        );
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide your logic under set-timeout. This will resolve your issue.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     forkJoin(
      this.myService.hasSetting(),
      this.myService.getDepartments()
    ).subscribe(
      ([hasSetting, departments]) => {
        
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.hasSetting = hasSetting;
    },200);
          this.departments = departments.map(item => {
            return {
              id: item.id,
              name: item.name
            }
          });
      }
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Also I don't like using random setTimeouts.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when component already checked for updates and wants to update the Visuals, and before updating checks again and sees that data is not the same...
very annoying.

but you can change your strategy a bit to get rid of it (I hope. I didn't test it)

you don't need to subscribe to your data, let the async pipe do it because it will use data at same time and also unsubscribes when you change to another route,
just use operators to shape the data the way you like and give it to html.

```
  data$: Observable<{hasSetting: boolean; departments: DropdownOption[] }>
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) {

    this.data$ = forkJoin(
      this.myService.hasSetting(),
      this.myService.getDepartments()
    ).pipe(map(x=>{
      return {
        hasSetting: x[0],
        departments: x[1]
      }
    }))
  }
```

```
  <div *ngIf="data$ | async as data" [ngClass]="data.hasSetting ? 'my-container' : 'opacity-div my-container'">    
    <dx-load-panel
      #loadPanel
      [visible]="!hasSetting" >
    </dx-load-panel>
  </div>
```